# how to use aggregate query result as column in another query having joins using stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions

i have a inner join query in stored procedure which is working fine. i need to inject a aggregate query in it so that it show an aggregated result in a new column

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tAIEACvEnG7sAisSoE2crYRrzCjIcvST/view?usp=sharing

i tried to inject aggregate query as a column TotalQty in my query

```
SELECT dbo.SO.Id,dbo.Customer.Name, dbo.Product.Name AS ProductName, dbo.SOD.SalePrice
,TotalQty = (select  SUM(dbo.SOD.Quantity) from [sod] o where o.SOId='68BD0F69-B957-439F-9AD0-180DF23EF42B' )

FROM     dbo.SOD INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Product ON dbo.SOD.ProductId = dbo.Product.Id RIGHT JOIN
                  dbo.SO ON dbo.SOD.SOId = dbo.SO.Id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Customer ON dbo.SO.CustomerId = dbo.Customer.Id
WHERE  (dbo.SO.Id = '68BD0F69-B957-439F-9AD0-180DF23EF42B')
```

But it says

> Column 'dbo.SO.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

or any other good Technique suggested will be appreciated.

Comment: GuidoG have a look https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vByyCvhJoJfp-nDb2oYq2f5R2hLQgauv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: mistakenly i wrote COUNT in query, its SUM

Answer (score 1):

so change AS :

```
SELECT dbo.SO.Id,dbo.Customer.Name, dbo.Product.Name AS ProductName, dbo.SOD.SalePrice
      ,(select  count(dbo.SOD.Quantity) from [sod] o where o.SOId='68BD0F69-B957-439F-9AD0-180DF23EF42B') AS TotalQty                    

FROM     dbo.SOD INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Product ON dbo.SOD.ProductId = dbo.Product.Id RIGHT JOIN
                  dbo.SO ON dbo.SOD.SOId = dbo.SO.Id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Customer ON dbo.SO.CustomerId = dbo.Customer.Id
WHERE  (dbo.SO.Id = '68BD0F69-B957-439F-9AD0-180DF23EF42B')
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the internal query, your characteristic is you used the `o.SOId` field on `where` and in other hand used `count` aggregate function so you should:

```
SELECT dbo.SO.Id,dbo.Customer.Name, dbo.Product.Name AS ProductName, 
       dbo.SOD.SalePrice
          ,count(dbo.SOD.Quantity)  AS TotalQty                      

    FROM     dbo.SOD INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Product ON dbo.SOD.ProductId = dbo.Product.Id RIGHT JOIN
                      dbo.SO ON dbo.SOD.SOId = dbo.SO.Id INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Customer ON dbo.SO.CustomerId = dbo.Customer.Id
    WHERE  (dbo.SO.Id = '68BD0F69-B957-439F-9AD0-180DF23EF42B')
    group by
        dbo.SO.Id,dbo.Customer.Name, dbo.Product.Name , dbo.SOD.SalePrice
```

Which will have the same output.

Comment: not executed :-( it says : Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: Then, do as the message says and replace, for example dbo.SO.Id with dbo.SOD.SOId. They have the same value and thus you group by at least a column from the outer reference.

Comment: Query executed successfully. but it is not what i required. please see image https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tAIEACvEnG7sAisSoE2crYRrzCjIcvST/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i required 'sum' of column values

Comment: Aggregating in the outer query changes the logic of the aggregation considerably - instead of aggregating based on rows in SOD the query now aggregates based on the rows returned by all of those joins.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you encourage others to help if you provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Using cryptic table names (are they tables? or views perhaps?) is not a healthy practice.  In addition, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve with your subquery. You attempted to use count but you label the value as "TotalQty" and you replied to a suggestion using "sum". Very confusing.

So since we don't have your tables, I used the common MS sample database AdventureWorks. Below are two examples of counting the quantity values from the detail table.

```
select Ord.SalesOrderID, Det.SalesOrderDetailID, 
       Cust.AccountNumber as CustName, -- too lazy to get actual name
       Prd.Name as ProductName, 
       Det.UnitPrice
       ,Counted.TotalQty  
--     TotalQty = (select  count(dbo.SOD.Quantity) from [sod] o where o.SOId='68BD0F69-B957-439F-9AD0-180DF23EF42B' )
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Ord 
inner join Sales.SalesOrderDetail as Det on Ord.SalesOrderID = Det.SalesOrderID
inner join Production.Product as Prd on Det.ProductID = Prd.ProductID
inner join Sales.Customer as Cust on Ord.CustomerID = Cust.CustomerID
cross apply (select count(DetCnt.OrderQty) as TotalQty from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as DetCnt where DetCnt.SalesOrderID = Det.SalesOrderID) as Counted
where Ord.SalesOrderID = 43659

select Ord.SalesOrderID, Det.SalesOrderDetailID, 
       Cust.AccountNumber as CustName, -- too lazy to get actual name
       Prd.Name as ProductName, 
       Det.UnitPrice
       , TotalQty = (select count(DetCnt.OrderQty) from Sales.SalesOrderDetail as DetCnt where DetCnt.SalesOrderID = Det.SalesOrderID) 
--     TotalQty = (select  count(dbo.SOD.Quantity) from [sod] o where o.SOId='68BD0F69-B957-439F-9AD0-180DF23EF42B' )
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Ord 
inner join Sales.SalesOrderDetail as Det on Ord.SalesOrderID = Det.SalesOrderID
inner join Production.Product as Prd on Det.ProductID = Prd.ProductID
inner join Sales.Customer as Cust on Ord.CustomerID = Cust.CustomerID
where Ord.SalesOrderID = 43659
```

I think that interpretation is correct but I don't know your schema. I added the PK of the detail table to help "see" the relationship between Order and Detail.

Examine the code closely. Notice how the query only refers to the specific PK value once (this would be your procedure's parameter). You use correlations and joins to limit the results as needed. And notice how much easier it is to understand the query since it uses names that are actual words - SalesOrder vs. SO. I don't think it makes much sense to right join your Detail table to the Order table - seems like a mistake. Your aggregation attempt is odd so I can't say if the value computed by these queries is correct.

I'll also note that you should not be passing the PK value of your table using a nvarchar parameter. Use the correct datatype to avoid the possibility that someone attempts to pass an actual string (e.g., N'Pick me') instead of a GUID value.

Comment: mistakenly i wrote COUNT in query, its SUM